# Is the restrict keyword meaningless on parameters of unique pointer types?

Tags: c, parameter-passing, memory-address, restrict, strict-aliasing

I've noticed a heavy use of the `restrict` keyword in one of our legacy projects.
I understand the rationale for `restrict`, but I question its useful-ness when applied to some of these functions.

Take the following two examples:

```
void funcA(int *restrict i){
    // ...
}

void funcB(int *restrict i, float *restrict f){
    // ...
}

int main(){

    int i = 1;
    float f = 3.14;

    funcA(&i);
    funcB(&i,&f);
}
```

Is there any valid reason one might tag the parameters of `funcA` and `funcB` with `restrict`?

`funcA` only takes 1 parameter.  How could it have the same address as anything else?

`funcB` takes parameters of different types.  If they were the same address, wouldn't that already be breaking the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: If the function may use global pointers/objects, I think `restrict` has value.

Comment: Concerning pointers to different types, C specified `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n,
FILE * restrict stream);` so it appear the standard committee sees value with `restrict` to different types.

Comment: Interesting.  Although isn't char somewhat of an exception because a char* is allowed to point to any other type.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: Yes, although I find it kind of odd that it’s there on `fgets`, because you wouldn’t think it would read from `s`…

Comment: @TrevorHickey Even if `char *` is special, there is `wchar_t *fgetws(wchar_t * restrict s,
int n, FILE * restrict stream);`

Comment: @TrevorHickey Side issue: a `char *` is _not_ allow to point to any other type, but any other object pointer.  Pointers to functions are problematic.

Comment: @Ryan I think the `restrict` goes deeper.  In _theory_, a field of structure `FILE` may be `char[]` and the `char *` buffer passed to `fgets()`  cannot alias that due to the two  `restrict`.

Comment: @chux Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: @chux: Ah, that’s true. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### `restrict` is *not* meaningless with single-pointer-parameter functions.

The `restrict` keyword is a declaration of intent, for improved optimization. It means that the objects pointed to by the given pointers will not be pointed to by *anything else* for the life of the (in this case) function parameters.

You don't show the code of the functions, so there may be static variables held inside. Restrict is a guarantee that those static variable don't alias the parameters.

There may be global variables not shown in your example. Restrict is a guarantee that those global variables don't alias the parameters.

In reality, you're right: it's likely that someone just went a little crazy with restrict. But restrict does *not* mean "this parameter and that parameter". It means "this pointer and *any other* pointer".

Comment: It means that one of two conditions will apply for the lifetime of the pointer, to every object accessed through it or pointers derived from it: (1) the object will not be modified by any means (during the pointer's lifetime), or (2) the object will not be accessed (including reads) by any means other than the pointer or others derived from it.  A `restrict`-qualified pointer may identify an object with static or automatic duration if the above conditions hold, but such objects may not be accessed "directly" during the lifetime of the pointer unless they are not modified during that lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

Given the function:

```
int foo(int *restrict p)
{
  *p = 3;
  bar();
  return *p;
}
```

a compiler can rather easily see--because of the `restrict` qualifier--that there is no legitimate way by which `bar()` can access `*p`.  It can thus optimize the above code into:

```
int foo(int *restrict p)
{
  bar();
  *p = 3;
  return 3;
}
```

and it can perform such optimization *without having to know anything whasoever about `bar()`*.  In the absence of the qualifier, the compiler would have to allow for the possibility that the caller might have e.g. passed the address of a global `int` which is modified by `bar()`, but because of `restrict` a compiler wouldn't have to worry about that.